# Class persistence in C#

Tags: c#

For a class project I am creating an RSS reader in C#. I have classes built for Channels, Feeds, and Articles.

My main class MainView  has a List Channels that will hold all the channels.

A Channel is just an organization class to hold feeds. (ie "Sports", "Technology" could be channels). A Channel has a List feeds that holds all the feeds. So if you have a channel, "Sports", and you create an RSS feed for ESPN, then I instantiate a Feed class.

However, I am not sure how to make my Channels List in the MainView class persist across all other classes. When I want to Add a Channel I create a pop-up form class (class addChannel) that allows user input. But in order to access the Channels List in the MainView I have to pass it into the constructor of the addChannel which just copies the List correct? So now when I manipulate the list in the addChannel class, I am not modifying the original right?

I am just so used to C where I can just pass pointers around and modify the original variable directly in memory. So before I continue making my program worst, I want to see if I am doing this all correct or not.

Let me know if there is any specific code you would like me to post.

This code is in my MainView class

```
 private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            addChannel newChannel = new addChannel(channelTree, Channels);
            newChannel.Show();

        }

 public List<Channel> Channels;
```

And this code is in the addChannel class

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            // I want to access the channelTree treeView here
            channel = new Channel(this.channelTitle.Text, this.channelDesc.Text);

            // Save the info to an XML doc
            channel.Save();

            // So here is where I want to add the channel to the List, but am not sure if it persists or not
            channels.Add(channel);


            // Now add it to the tree view
            treeView.Nodes.Add(channel.Title);

            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: *I am not modifying the original right?* No youe probably *are modifying* the original list. That's what reference types are about. No one could say for sure without seeing your constructor and how you call it.

Comment: So sending the original Channels list into a constructor will pass by reference automatically and not by value?

Comment: I wish you hadn't said by reference and by value since there's a lot of confusion about that. But yes. Jon Skeet has a [good article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) on what it really means

Comment: @ConradFrix I updated my post with some code now

Comment: Thanks for that article. I didn't know C# divided the data types between Reference types and Value types.. my class kind of just jumps us straight into building a C# project rather than learning C# first.

Comment: +1 to your question for being willing to learn the inner workings of C#. It's a little scary that your instructor is having you code without explaining the nuances of the language - sort of like people who write .NET apps completely in the designer without ever bothering to understand what is happening "behind the scenes."  It can be done, but will ultimately limit them, IMO.  Hopefully your instructor will spend some time on the underpinnings of the language at some point.

Comment: Because of your C background, you might also find [this comparison between pointers and references](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/07/references-and-pointers-part-one.aspx) useful.  It's written by Eric Lippert, who until recently worked on the C# compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not resetting `MainView.Channels` someplace (e.g. `this.Channels = new List<Channels>;` or `this.Channels = GetMeSomeChannels();` then when you call  `channels.Add(channel);` this is adding to same list since both variables reference the same List.

For example the following [demo](http://ideone.com/0H96Mw) Passes a `List<string>` to another class. The other class will then add a string to the list. Then that new string is observed by both classes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{


    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> Channels = new List<string>() {"a","b", "c"};
        AddChannel ac = new AddChannel(Channels);
                ac.AddSomthing("foo");

                foreach(var s in Channels)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

    }


}
public class AddChannel 
{
        private List<string> Channels {get;set;}
    public AddChannel(List<string> Channels )
        {
        this.Channels = Channels ; 
    }

        public void AddSomthing(string s)
        {
            this.Channels.Add(s);
        }

}
```

Additional reading

- [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) by Jon Skeet